# Select blog posts where a user has not commented

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

A post has many comments. A comment (content, author_id) is authored by a user.

How do I retrieve blog posts where a given user (author_id = 1) has not commented?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: A post has a title and content. A comment has a content, author_id and post_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM post p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM comment c
                         WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id
                             AND c.author_id = 1)
```

You could also do this with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM post p
        LEFT JOIN comment c
            ON p.post_id = c.post_id
                AND c.author_id = 1
    WHERE c.post_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In regular 'ole SQL, this would look like this:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM posts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM comments c
    WHERE p.post_id = c.post_id
      AND c.author_id = 1
)
```

I'm not sure how you do this with Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord syntax.